# How to find Laurent expansion

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

I have been presented with the function $g(z) = \frac{2z}{z^2 + z^3}$ and asked to find the Laurent expansion around the point $z=0$.

I split the function into partial fractions to obtain $g(z) = \frac{2}{z} - \frac{2}{1+z}$, but do not know where to go from here.

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{2z}{z^2+z^3}=\frac {2z}{ z^2}\cdot \frac 1{1+z}=\frac 2 z\cdot\sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^kz^k=\sum_{k=-1}^\infty-2(-1)^kz^k$$

No need for fraction decomposition.

Answer (score 1):

So you've obtained $g(x) = \frac{2}{z} - \frac{2}{1+z}$. The first part of it looks to be in the proper form already. How can you change something of the form $\frac{1}{1+z}$ into powers of $z$? You should be thinking of geometric sum.

$$\frac{1}{1+z} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n z^n$$

Comment: It seemed to be correct and I just checked it to be correct as well.

Comment: Does this mean it becomes 2/z -2sum(z^n)? @T.S.L

Comment: Yes, you just plug it in.

Answer (score 0):

> The function $$g(z)=\frac{2}{z}-\frac{2}{1+z}$$ has two simple poles at $0$ and $-1$.

We observe the fraction $\frac{2}{z}$ is already the principal part of the Laurent expansion at $z=0$. We can keep the focus on the other fraction.

> Since we want to find a Laurent expansion with center $0$, we look at the other pole $-1$ and have to distuinguish two regions.
>
> \begin{align*}
>  |z|<1,\qquad\quad
>  1<|z|
>  \end{align*}
>
> - The first region $ |z|<1$ is a disc with center $0$, radius $1$ and the pole $-1$ at the boundary of the disc. In the *interior* of this disc the fraction with pole $-1$ admits a representation as *power series* at $z=0$.
> - The second region $1<|z|$ containing all points outside the disc with center $0$ and radius $1$ admits for all fractions a representation as principal part of a Laurent series at $z=0$.

A power series expansion of $\frac{1}{z+a}$ at $z=0$ is
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{z+a}
&=\frac{1}{a}\frac{1}{1+\frac{z}{a}}
=\frac{1}{a}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(-\frac{1}{a}\right)^nz^n\\
&=-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(-\frac{1}{a}\right)^{n+1}z^n\\
\end{align*}
The principal part of $\frac{1}{z+a}$ at $z=0$ is
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{z+a}&=\frac{1}{z}\frac{1}{1+\frac{a}{z}}=\frac{1}{z}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-a)^n\frac{1}{z^n}\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-a)^{n-1}\frac{1}{z^n}\\
\end{align*}

> We can now obtain the Laurent expansion of $g(x)$ at $z=0$ for both regions
>
> - *Region 1:* $|z|<1$
>
> \begin{align*}
> g(z)&=\frac{2}{z}-2\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^nz^n=2\sum_{n=-1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n+1}z^n\\
> \end{align*}
>
> - *Region 2:* $1<|z|$
>
> \begin{align*}
> g(z)&=\frac{2}{z}-2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n-1}\frac{1}{z^n}=2\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}(-1)^{n}\frac{1}{z^n}\\
> \end{align*}